# How to compare filenames in bash

Tags: bash

I need to compare if "dir1" has the same files as "dir2" and ideally remove the similar contents in "dir2".

So far i have tried using the find command:

```
    $ find "$dir1" "$dir2/" "$dir2/" -printf '%P\n' | sort | uniq -u^C
```

But this doesn't work cause, while the filename are similar, the extension of the files are different in the two folders.

so how do i go about comparing filenames in bash?

Comment: The extension is part of the filename, it isn't something distinct as it was in MS-DOS. Further, filenames are plain strings, so all you probably need to look up is string manipulations in BASH.

Comment: Use a capable scripting language, like Python or Perl.

Comment: You can use `diff` on directories and it'll tell you which files are unique to each directory. If you add a specific example of what you want to achieve on an example directory structure, I might be able to see if that could be helpful or not.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just need to use a loop:

```
for path in "$dir1"/*; do
  base=${path##*/}  # remove everything up to and including the last / to get the name
  if [ -e "$dir2/$base" ]; then
    echo rm -r "$dir2/$base"
  fi
done
```

Loop through everything in `$dir1` and if `$dir2` has a file with the same name, then remove it.

Remove the `echo` when you're happy that the script is going to remove the right files.